# Task.Factory.StartNew with a canceled token has the status running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I thought that a task initialized with Task.Factory.StartNew with a canceled token should not be scheduled, run, and should end with a status of Canceled. But quite by accident in the VS 2019 on .NET 5, I have noticed that very rarely a task has a running status.

In this case, the operation inside the task is obviously not performed. Because in my example 1 is not output to the console. Can anyone explain what is actually happening?

**Question**. Why does the task in this example sometimes have the status running, although it obviously does not work?

**UPD**. Checked on VS 2022 on .NET 6. Same thing.

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(1);
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            Task t1 = new Task(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            Task t2 = new Task(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            Task t3 = new Task(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            Task t4 = new Task(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            Task t5 = new Task(() => { }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);           
           
            Console.WriteLine($"t1: {t1.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t2: {t2.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t3: {t3.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t4: {t4.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t5: {t5.Status}");

            Task t6 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(1);
                }

            }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            Console.WriteLine($"t6: {t6.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t6: {t6.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t6: {t6.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"t6: {t6.Status}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because a task must be initialized (run) in order to know it will be canceled. So on occasion, depending upon the CPU load at the time, the Task is still running itself into a cancellation at the time the console writes this line.

Comment: It seems like delegate tasks are always going thru the "Running" state. See Stephen Clearys [tour of tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html)

Comment: @JonasH, It's said there: "The task is in the Running state when the delegate of the Delegate Task is actually executing." Obviously, in my example, the method in the task is not executed. 1 is not displayed in the console. Did the author come up with the data in this article himself? I don't see links to sources or source code.

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces, You can initialize a task with a constructor using a canceled token and it will be canceled immediately, you won't even be able to start it with the Start method. I changed the code in the example a little so that 1 is displayed in the console indefinitely. And 1 is still not printed to the console.

Comment: I would assume the threadpool picks a task from the queue, sets it as running, then checks any associated cancellation-token. But I have no authoritative sources, even if I would place a fairly high confidence on Stephen Cleary.  If you are really curious I guess you should be able to check the source code. But does it matter? Does it have any practical importance?

Comment: @JonasH, Just curious. Why waste a resource on changing the status of a task to the status of running if the task is not running. For me, the main thing is that the task actually does not work.

Comment: @NikVladi "You can initialize a task with a constructor using a canceled token and it will be canceled immediately" There is no such thing as immediate. A task cannot be canceled unless it is running. What you view as immediate is actually several hundred to several million nanoseconds of time. Instantaneous to you, sure... your computer however can perform many billions of operations per second. Thats a lot of time in reality, almost enough to sometimes show the task as running as the console.writteline goes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, `Running` status is never reached with your code, both with Framework 4.7.2 and with .NET 6 (VS 2019). As @JonasH suggested, I took a look at the code. Below is one possible explanation.
In the code below, `ExecuteEntryUnsafe` is called by the `TaskScheduler` (here the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`) after the Task is scheduled to run. I tried with a basic custom scheduler, in this case the method called is `ExecuteEntry()` with some additional securities to prevent double invocation. But the explanation remains valid.
*Disclaimer: I am very far from having the reputation or knowledge as guys like Stephen Cleary, so please take this answer with some caution. If this is not correct, I'll delete it.*

```
//---------
// Task.cs
//---------

internal void ExecuteEntryUnsafe(Thread? threadPoolThread)
{
    // [SOURCE comment] Remember that we started running the task delegate
    // This is what actually makes the status show as Running (see source):
    // ...
    // int sf = m_stateFlags;
    // 
    // if ((sf & TASK_STATE_FAULTED) != 0) rval = TaskStatus.Faulted;
    // else if ((sf & TASK_STATE_CANCELED) != 0) rval = TaskStatus.Canceled;
    // else if ((sf & TASK_STATE_RAN_TO_COMPLETION) != 0) rval = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
    // else if ((sf & TASK_STATE_WAITING_ON_CHILDREN) != 0) rval = TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete;
    // else if ((sf & TASK_STATE_DELEGATE_INVOKED) != 0) rval = TaskStatus.Running; <-- here
    // ...

    m_stateFlags |= (int)TaskStateFlags.DelegateInvoked;

    // *** 
    // On your machine, execution probably switches back to main thread for a fraction of a second here.
    // Hence one of your WriteLines outputs "Running". But this means "delegate was invoked", not necessarily "code is executing".
    // On my machine this does not happen, so I do not see Running status.
    // *** 

    if (!IsCancellationRequested & !IsCanceled)
    {
        ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref t_currentTask, threadPoolThread);
    }
    else
    {
        // As Cancellation is requested this will be executed, even if IsCancelled is false.
        ExecuteEntryCancellationRequestedOrCanceled(); 
    }
}

// ...

internal void ExecuteEntryCancellationRequestedOrCanceled()
{
    // If Task is cancelled; this is different that "is cancellation requested". So this block is executed.
    if (!IsCanceled) 
    {
        // Set Cancelled flag.
        int prevState = Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_stateFlags, m_stateFlags | (int)TaskStateFlags.Canceled);

        // If previous state was not yet Cancelled, perform some cleanup.
        if ((prevState & (int)TaskStateFlags.Canceled) == 0)
        {
            CancellationCleanupLogic();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonasH I edited the answer to show this in the beginning of the code (`[SOURCE comment]`). Thanks.

Comment: @evilmandarine, Thanks, edited the code a little, adding tasks. Made about a hundred attempts ctrl + f5. Try it. I'm not kidding. It's happening again.

Comment: @NikVladi You can add 1000 tasks, it does not change the explanation, which is on my answer. On my machine it happened with your previous code *while debugging and when a breakpoint was hit on worker thread*, after the status switch, but before cancellation check. Which actually explains the behavior, and it's the expected behavior: the Task code for which cancellation was **requested** does not execute. Whether the Task status switches to "Running" (= delegate invoked) for a nanosecond or not does not matter, as JonasH said in another comment. Here "running" means "delegate was invoked".